# Как убрать ненужные столбцы из присоединяемой при помощи JOIN таблицы?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

Есть 2 таблицы, которые я объединяю при помощи JOIN:

```
SELECT id, ... FROM cars JOIN cities ON ...
```

Мне надо сделать, чтобы колонка id из cities не попадала в выборку, иначе я получаю 2 колонки id. Как убрать второй id из выборки?

Answer (score 1):

Вы должны явно указать, из какой таблицы id вы хотите возвращать

```
SELECT cars.id, ... FROM cars JOIN cities ON ...
```

Comment: Причём, если не указать, то ведь ещё и ругаться будет наверняка на неоднозначность выборки

Comment: Причём, во множестве источников присвоение алиасов таблицам и указание их в названии полей считается хорошей практикой и всячески рекомендуется.

Comment: *Вы можете явно указать, из какой таблицы id вы хотите возвращать* Я бы сказал не "можете", а "должны" или "обязаны". Более того, настоятельно рекомендуется в любом запросе, использующем более одной таблицы (даже если это две копии одной таблицы) указывать алиас таблицы для КАЖДОГО поля. А поля без алиаса таблицы - это соответственно имена выходного набора (в т.ч. в GROUP BY / HAVING / ORDER BY).

Comment: @Akina, согласен, поправил

Comment: отлично, но это не решает моей проблемы. Явно я тоже указываю, просто здесь упростил для понимания. Если я присоединяю JOIN-ом вторую таблицу, то для неё я как-то могу указать те столбцы, которые мне нужны?

Answer (score 0):

> отлично, но это не решает моей проблемы. Явно я тоже указываю, просто здесь упростил для понимания. Если я присоединяю JOIN-ом вторую таблицу, то для неё я как-то могу указать те столбцы, которые мне нужны?

Разумеется:

SELECT c.id, c.Name, c. ..., s.Name, s. ... FROM cars с JOIN cities s ON c.CityId = s.ID